# Is a 2 hour connection feasible at Istanbul Sabiha Gokcen airport?

Tags: transit, short-connections, connecting-flights, saw

I am flying from Bucharest to Tirana, Albana, and will transit at the Sabiha Gokcen airport in Istanbul. I have a 2-hour layover before the connecting flight. Is this enough time to make it to my flight to Tirana?